# Translation of the statements of theorems presented in a German paper of Gaschütz

Tags: group-theory, translation-request, mathematical-german

I would appreciate some help in translating the statements of the theorems contained in the following paper of Gaschütz on the Frattini subgroup: "Über die $\Phi$-Untergruppe endlicher Gruppen".

Many thanks and I'm willing to offer compensation for this.

[image: Satz 1]
[image: Satz 2]
[image: Satz 3]

[image: Satz 4]
[image: Satz 5]
[image: Satz 6]
[image: Satz 7]
[image: Satz 8]
[image: Satz 9]
[image: Satz 10]
[image: Satz 11]
[image: Satz 12]
[image: Satz 13]
[image: Satz 14]
[image: Satz 15]
[image: Satz 16]
[image: Satz 17]

Comment: I can only access the first two pages - if you only need the theorems, can't you quote them here?

Comment: Yes, good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Feel free to edit** *, as I am not about the translation of certain terms and I cannot read german fractura very well. (Perhaps you might also want to leave a comment for saying what you changed and why you changed it.)*

*I denote the words I was not sure how to translate and comments with questionmarks and $[]$ brackets.*

> **Definitions:**
>
> - $A(G)$: the automorphism group of $G$.
> - $J(G)$: the group of inner automorphisms of $G$.
> - $Z(G)$: the centre of $G$.
> - $K(G)$: the commutator subgroup of $G$.
> - $L(G)$: the maximal nilpotent subgroup of $G$.
> - $\Phi(G)$: the intersection of the maximal subgroups of $G$.
> - $\Delta(G)$: the intersection of the maximal and non-invariant subgroups of $G$.
> - If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $G=N\overline{G}$, where $\overline{G}$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $\overline{G}\subset G$ ($N\cap\overline{G}=1$, resp.), we say that $G$ *splits* (*decomposes*, resp.) over $G$.
> - If $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of $A(G)$, a group $R$ is $\Gamma$-*fully-reducible* if $R$ is a product of minimal subgroups of $R$ invariant under $\Gamma$. In particular, if $R$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, and $\Gamma$ the group of automorphisms of $R$ induced by transformations by the elements of $G$ [I take this to mean conjugation. -BMS], and $R$ is $\Gamma$-fully-reducible, we say that $R$ is $G$-*fully-reducible*.
> - Let $N$ be an arbitrary normal subgroup of $G$. $S_{G}(N)$ denotes the product of the minimal normal subgroups of $G$ in $N$. $S_{G}(N)$ is the maximal $G$-fully-reducible normal subgroup contained in $N$. We denote by $R_{G}(N)$ the intersection of the normal subgroups of $G$ maximal in $N$. $N/R_{G}(N)$ is $G/R_{G}(N)$-fully-reducible, and $R_{G}(N)$ contains no normal subgroup $M$ of $G$ with $G/M$-fully-reducible factor group $N/M$. We call $S_{G}(G)$ the *Sockel* of $G$ and write simply $S(G)$.

**Theorem 1:** Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then $N \subseteq \Phi(G)$ if and only if $G$ does not split over $N$.

**Theorem 2:** Let $\Psi$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, $\Psi\subseteq \Phi(G)$. Then $\Phi(G/\Psi) = \Phi(G) /\Psi$.

**Theorem 3:** If $\sigma$ is a homomorphism with domain $G$, then $$(2.1) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\sigma\Phi(G)\subseteq \Phi(\sigma G)\;.$$

**Theorem 4:** $K(G) \cap Z(G) \subseteq \Phi(G)$.

**Theorem 5:** If $N$ is a normal supgroup and $U$ a subgroup of $G$, and $N \subseteq \Phi(U)$, then $N \subseteq \Phi(G)$.

**Theorem 6).** If $G = M \times N$. then $\Phi(G) = \Phi(M) \times \Phi(N)$.

**Theorem 7:** If $A$ is an Abelian normal subgroup of $G$, and $$(2.5)\qquad\qquad\qquad A \cap \Phi(G) = 1\;,$$ then $G$ decomposes over $A$. Moreover, $A$ is $G$-fully-reducible.

**Theorem 8:** If $A$ is an Abelian normal subgroup of $G$, then $R_{G}(A) \subseteq \Phi(G)$.

**Theorem 9:** If $L$ is nilpotent, then $\Phi(L) = 1$ if and only if $L$ is a direct product of groups of prime order.

**Theorem 10:** Let $M$ and $\Psi$ be normal supgroups of $G$, $\Psi \subseteq M \cap \Phi(G)$ and $M / \Psi$ nilpotent. Then $M$ is nilpotent.

**Theorem 11:** Let $\Psi$ be a normal supgroup of $G$, $\Psi \subseteq \Phi(G)$. Then $$(4.1)\qquad\qquad\qquad J(\Psi) \subseteq \Phi(A(\Psi))\;.$$

**Theorem 12:** In a $\Phi$-free group $F$, $L(F)$ is the product of the minimal Abelian normal subgroups of $F$.

**Theorem 13:** $L(G) / \Phi(G)$ is the product of the minimal Abelian normal subgroups of $G/\Phi(G)$.

**Theorem 14:** A group is $\Phi$-free if and only if it decomposes over the Abelian component of its *Sockel*.

**Theorem 15:** In a $\Phi$-free group $F$,

$$(5.4) \qquad\qquad\qquad Z(F/Z(F)) = Z(F) / Z (F)$$ and

$$(5.5) \qquad \qquad\qquad Z (F) = \Delta(F)\;.$$

**Theorem 16:** For an arbitrary $G$, $\Delta(G)$ is nilpotent.

**Theorem 17:** Let $S$ be a direct product of simple groups and $\{\Gamma\}$ a complete system of representatives of the classes of $A(S)$ conjugated subgroups of $A(S)$ with the following properties:

$(I): \quad S_\alpha$ is $\Gamma_\alpha$-fully-reducible

$(II): \quad J(S_\eta) \subseteq \Gamma$

If $\Gamma$ runs through this system of representatives, then the groups $F_\Gamma$ with the elements $(a,\gamma)$, $a\in S_\alpha$, $\gamma \in \Gamma$, and the operation defined by

$$(a,\gamma) (b,\delta) = (ab^{\gamma_\alpha},\gamma \delta)$$

are a complete system of representatives of the types of the $\Phi$-free groups of a *Sockel* of type $S$.

Comment: Your $\mathcal{R}$ in Thm. 1 should be $\mathcal{N}$. The paper contains a definition of *splits over* $\mathcal{N}$: If $\mathcal{N}$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathcal{G}$, and $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{N}\overline{\mathcal{G}}$, where $\overline{\mathcal{G}}$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal{G}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{G}}\subset\mathcal{G}$ ($\mathcal{N}\cap\overline{\mathcal{G}}=1$, resp.), we say that $\mathcal{G}$ *splits* (*decomposes*, resp.) over $\mathscr{N}$. I’ve no idea what the proper English terminology is; this is very much not my field.

Comment: In Theorem 3: homomorph**ic**. In theorem 4, the letters are $\mathfrak{K}$, $\mathfrak{Z}$, $K$ and $Z$.

Comment: In my other comment I used *split* for *zerspalten* and *decompose* for *zerfallen*. The latter appears in Thm. 7.

Comment: $A(\mathcal{G})$ is the automorphism group of $\mathcal{G}$. If $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of $A(\mathcal{G})$, a group $\mathcal{R}$ is $\Gamma$-*fully-reducible* if $\mathcal{R}$ is a product of minimal subgroups of $\mathcal{R}$ invariant under $\Gamma$. In particular, if $\mathcal{R}$ is a normal subgroup of a group $\mathcal{G}$, and $\Gamma$ the group of automorphisms of $\mathcal{R}$ induced by transformations with the elements of $\mathcal{G}$ [I take this to mean conjugation], and $\mathcal{R}$ is $\Gamma$-fully-reducible, we say that $\mathcal{R}$ is $\mathcal{G}$-*fully-reducible*.

Comment: Feel free to edit now, I incorporated your suggestions where I knew it, but I hope you can contribute where I am still not sure.

Comment: I'll give it a shot at writing the theorems as they would appear in a modern textbook.

Comment: I think that I’ve done what I can now. I left *Sockel* untranslated but added the definition in the paper.

Comment: There's not much point in retaining the original text's fraktur, or the changes in letters in every theorem. I wish I'd be allowed to make the changes I want so that it reads easily.

Comment: @the_fox: There’s no fraktur in the answer as it now stands.

Comment: There's mathcal, which I find completely unnecessary. Also, the operator names are strange.

Comment: @the_fox: I can get rid of the mathcal easily enough; it wasn’t my idea anyway. Hang on a bit.