# Two definitions of the radical of a module over a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ is an $R$-module. There are two definitions of the radical of $M$ in the literature. First definition is
$$
\operatorname{Rad}(M)=\bigcap \{N \mid N \text{ is a maximal submodule of } M\},
$$
which gives us a submodule of $M$. The second definition is
$$
\operatorname{rad}(M) = \bigcap \{m \subset R \mid  m \text{ is a maximal ideal and }\operatorname{Ann}(M) \subset m\},
$$
which is an ideal. This definition is used, for example, in the book "A term of Commutative Algebra" by Altman and Kleiman.

Is it true that $\operatorname{rad}(M) M = \operatorname{Rad}(M)$?

I see how to show that
$$
\bigcap_{m \text{ is maximal ideal}} mM=\operatorname{Rad}(M),
$$
but I have problems showing that $\operatorname{rad}(M)M = \bigcap_{m \text{ is maximal ideal}} mM$. If this is not correct, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Are you sure you got the first definition correct? Isn't it $
\operatorname{Rad}(M)=\bigcap \{\textbf{Ann}(N) \mid N \text{ is a maximal submodule of } M\}$, so that it is also an ideal? (The question of whether they are equal is then still an issue of course)
$

Comment: (bold face for emphasis, not part of standard notation)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that first definition is what I want. This definition can be found in many non-commutative ring theory books and also in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_a_module

Comment: Hmm, interesting! I only knew radicals as ideals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the desired equality does not hold, and can in fact fail very acutely! For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}$. Then $M$ has no maximal submodules (why?), and so in particular we have $\text{Rad}(M)=M$. However, the annihilator of $M$ is clearly just the ideal $(0)<\mathbb{Z}$, so $\text{rad}(M)$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$, which is $(0)$. Hence $\text{rad}(M)M=\{0\}$, which is certainly not equal to $M$.

For an example where $M$ does have maximal submodules, let $M=\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Z}$, with $R=\mathbb{Z}$ as above. By lemma 2 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902615/jacobson-radical-and-frattini-group/3902761#3902761), $$\text{Rad}(M)=\text{Rad}(\mathbb{Q})\times\text{Rad}(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Q}\times\{0\},$$ which is not all of $M$. (In particular, $\mathbb{Q}\times(p)$ is a maximal submodule of $M$ for any $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ prime.) However, we again have $\text{Ann}(M)=(0)$ and thus $\text{rad}(M)=(0)$, so this gives another counterexample.

Comment: I understand your example, $\mathbb{Q}$ has no maximal submodules because there are no maps $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{F}_p$. But to be honest, I want to see more examples of this sort, where there are maximal submodules in $M$.

Comment: @Alex indeed, that argument works! re: your question, you can actually extend the counterexample $\mathbb{Q}$ to a counterexample that *does* have maximal submodules fairly easy; I've given an example above, hopefully it's helpful :)